# DHCP IP discovery, offer, request, ack

Tags: request, ip, dhcp

Why does my DHCP server use my old ip adress as destination?

0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 -> discovery

192.168.0.1 - **192.168.0.100** -> offer

0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 -> request

192.168.0.1 - **192.168.0.100** -> ACK

Normally it should use 255.255.255.255.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine requesting an IP address is not filtering the received packets based on destination address and so it doesn't matter what address is placed as the destination.

The server machine has an ARP entry that connects an IP address to a given Ethernet MAC address (which is how you really contact the client) and so DHCP server process can use that address to create a directed reply rather than broadcasting to the entire subnet.  To create a directed reply without some specific IP address would require the DHCP server to create its own UDP packets rather than just letting the system do it.